# getitem for custom dataloader is not working

Tags: pytorch

I am new to deep learning and Pytorch. I have data set of 6000 images that have all four classes in a single folder. I have a .csv file that has an image name and there corresponding one hot encoded representation ([Ground_Truth_Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFXfP.png)). I want to bind the image name to its label, so I can feed it into the neural network. I found that a custom Data Loader can be used for this. I tried the following code snippet in PyCharm:

```html
class DFUDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.DFU = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.DFU)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
            img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.DFU.iloc[idx, 0])  # image names
            image = io.imread(img_name)
            img_label = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.DFU.iloc[0, idx[1:]])  # image labels
            sample = {'image': image, 'img_label': img_label}
            return sample


DFU_dataset = DFUDataset(
    csv_file='C:/Users/aleems2/Desktop/dfu/DFUC2021_trainset_210427/DFUC2021_train/Labelled_data_ground_truth.csv',
    root_dir="C:/Users/aleems2/Desktop/dfu/DFUC2021_trainset_210427/DFUC2021_train/Labelled_test_images")
```

However, when I am trying to debug the code then, a blue circle comes right beside **getitem** ([Blue circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90EQb.png)), and the debugger does not go to this function. It just runs def **init**, and then comes out of class DFUDataset(Dataset). I do not know what to override getitem with.
I have spent hours on this, but could not figure it out.

Comment: What do you expect this to do if `idx` isn't a tensor?

Comment: I want to combine the image name from .csv file to the label for that image. I am attaching .csv file screenshot in original question.

Comment: @user15723449 No the question is what do you want to do when `idx` isn't a tensor? Because that seems to be the problem here.

Comment: BTW. You don't need to think to much about the blue dot. And you can debug `__getitem__` by add `x = DFU_dataset[0]`